# Are these equivalent answers?

Tags: calculus, integration

The question:
$$\int{(7x-2)(3x+2)^{1/2}dx}$$
is done by some complicated methods in my Textbook and the answer they got is:
$$\frac{14}{45}(3x+2)^{5/2}-\frac{40}{27}(3x+2)^{3/2}+c$$
But I managed to do it using integration by parts and I got the answer as:
$$x(7x-2)(3x+2)^{1/2}-\frac79(3x+2)^{3/2}+\frac{14}3(3x+2)^{1/2}+c$$
Are both the answers equivalent?.If I'm wrong,feel free to correct me.

If they're not equivalent,does that mean that it can't be done by parts?

Comment: They aren't equivalent - for one, they disagree at $x=0$.

Comment: You can test for equivalence yourself. Here's a general method. Just use bounds (to simulate a definite integral calculation). Since this is a rational function, you can choose an upper bound to be transcendental (like $\pi$) and a convenient lower bound like $0$. That way if the two come out to be equal (within the limit of accuracy) on your calculator you know it's not an algebraic coincidence.

Comment: @JohnDoe: this is not conclusive, there are unknown integration constants.

Comment: Compute the derivatives of both expressions.

Comment: @YvesDaoust yes, those weren't there when I made the comment. One can calculate each of these expressions at another point and subtract the two results and this will show disagreement anyway.

Comment: Their graphs arent shaped the same, so im guessing no

Comment: @JohnDoe: yes, you need two points (provided you don't cross a singularity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

factorizing your first term(solution) we get
$${\frac {2\, \left( 3\,x+2 \right) ^{3/2} \left( 63\,x-58 \right) }{135
}}
+C$$ this is the right solution
your second one is (simplified)
$$1/9\,\sqrt {3\,x+2} \left( 63\,{x}^{2}-39\,x+28 \right) $$ and this is wrong